# How to save a list in a Model Layer in Android?

Tags: android, model-view-controller

I am an intermediate Android Developer. I am intending to save a list into my Model layer, is it the right way to declare it?

```
    public class Message {

    private UUID mId;
    private String mTopic;
    private String mPayload;

    public Message() {
        mId = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getTopic() {
        return mTopic;
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        mTopic = topic;
    }

    public String getPayload() {
        return mPayload;
    }

    public void setPayload(String payload) {
        mPayload = payload;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

You have to take **ArrayList** for your **Model** class, like below:

```
private ArrayList<Message> mMessageList = new ArrayList<Message>();
```

**Save** data in **arraylist**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    Message mMessageModel = new Message();
    mMessageModel.setTopic(Your_Topic);
    // other stuff

    mMessageList.add(mMessageModel);
}
```

**Get** data from **arraylist**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mMessageList.size(); i++){
    Message mMessageModel = mMessageList.get(i);
    String My_Topic = mMessageModel.getTopic();
    // other stuff

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great help. :)

Comment: @Barbatos, Glad to help you.